# How do I stop profile photo shrinking when moving a picture from an album to my profile picture?

Tags: facebook, profile

How do I stop profile photo shrinking when uploading a profile picture?

I currently have many huge and clear profile pictures uploaded, but cannot upload new photos just as big and clear.

I have already followed these instructions:
https://web.facebook.com/help/266520536764594
and shrunk my photo to 2048px and 100KB, yet when I upload to my profile picture, it is very poor quality and shrinks as usual.

If you could possible solve this, please let me know.